# Align child widgets to a positioned child widget

Tags: flutter

I need to position a child widget (w1) at a relative position to its parent (in the example see the white box at 30%), and to position two other child widgets (w2, w3) to the right and left.

The positioned child (w1) is the anchor and should remain in 30%, regardless of w2 and w3 width, while the other child widgets should positioned accordingly.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I tried to use Stack widget as the parent
The problem is I can't place the position child at 30%, as it only excepts const values

I also tried to placed them in Container with FractionalOffset - it works for single children, but I can't add another children to this Container.

```
 Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.blue[200],
      alignment: const FractionalOffset(0.3, 0),
      child: Text("50",style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black))),
```

Comment: "as it only excepts const values" - what const values do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CompositedTransformTarget` widget.

```dart
class TestF133 extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestF133({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LayerLink link = LayerLink();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(.3, 0),
            child: CompositedTransformTarget(
              link: link,
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50, // you can handle theses
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: link,
            followerAnchor: Alignment.centerLeft,
            targetAnchor: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Text("dynamic right Text"),
          ),
          CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: link,
            followerAnchor: Alignment.centerRight,
            targetAnchor: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text("dynamic left Text"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: plus for using `CompositedTransformFollower` - i forgot to add that `CompositedTransformFollower` works even if a target is a list view item (returned from `ListViee.builder`) so if you scroll list view the follower scrolls too